# ksh conditional

Tags: conditional-statements, ksh

There is something simple I am over looking.

```
if [ ${FILEDATE} -gt ${MIN} ]; then
    echo $MAX
fi
```

The above code works, but not this:

```
if [ ${FILEDATE} -gt ${MIN} ||  ${FILEDATE} -lt ${MAX}]; then
    echo $MAX
fi
```

There must be some syntax problem, but the references I have found look identical to what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[` (on my system it is at `/usr/bin/[`) is actually a program or `builtin` which expects an expression just like [`test(1)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html) does. The peculiarity with `[` is, that it has to be wrapped up with a closing `]`.

So calling `[` and combining different expressions is possible by using `&&` and `||` operators from the shell:

`if [ ${FILEDATE} -gt ${MIN} ] || [ ${FILEDATE} -lt ${MAX} ]; then #...` Should work just fine.

*You might also consider to put the variable expansions inside* `""` *to get nice behavior even if some variable isn't defined ;)*

See also: [Unix test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Where I do: 'if [[ ${FILEDATE} -gt ${MIN}] || [${FILEDATE} -lt ${MAX}]]; then' it gives me an error saying that the comma was unexpected.

Comment: 'if [ ${FILEDATE} -gt ${MIN}] || [${FILEDATE} -lt ${MAX}]; then' Gives me an error of 'missing bracket'

Comment: You also have to understand that `[` have to be separated by other *arguments* to the command!

Comment: OK, it turns that I didn't have white space around the brackets.  How embarrassing.